# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: How long was this open for? I see it's too late to reply now. Should question be modified to reflect it's now closed. I recommend it stay open longer if you do this again.

Comment: @Duncan, It's open for a full week, so regular visitors shouldn't miss it.

Comment: Since only 4-6 people responded, I still recommend keeping it open for longer in future. I'd consider 'weekly' visitors 'regular' and you are likely to miss them. As well as people taking a week off. I'd recommend trying to open to wider audience whenever possible. I just use myself as an example. I'm a 'top ten' beta user and I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results - Mean Net Score: 0.5

- [What WPA projects took place in my (or my relatives') hometown?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3946/how-can-i-find-out-what-wpa-projects-took-place-in-my-or-my-relatives-hometow)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What uses are there for the Social Security Number (SSN) of a deceased ancestor?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/what-uses-are-there-for-the-social-security-number-ssn-of-a-deceased-ancestor)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is the term "baptism" or "christening" more accurate in old parish registers?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/is-the-term-baptism-or-christening-more-accurate-in-old-parish-registers)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I correct Ellis Island Indexes?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/how-can-i-correct-ellis-island-indexes)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do I perform a biographical interview?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/how-do-i-perform-a-biographical-interview)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to determine Royal Navy Reserves (RNR) service record number of particular individual?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/how-to-determine-royal-navy-reserves-rnr-service-record-number-of-particular-i)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to index your own digitalized records?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/how-to-index-your-own-digitalized-records)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is there a gramplet or report for getting the list of surnames from gramps?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/is-there-a-gramplet-or-report-for-getting-the-list-of-surnames-from-gramps)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is there a legal standard for Heraldry & Family Coats of Arms in U.S.?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3951/is-there-a-legal-standard-for-heraldry-family-coats-of-arms-in-u-s)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does this headwear tell me anything about the individual wearing it?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3997/does-this-headwear-tell-me-anything-about-the-individual-wearing-it)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Comment: I think the number of surnames in Gramps question results were skewed after I left an answer half-way through